# IIS express and IIS7 path

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5

I expert,
I need to update some dll on a web program running in IIS7. I prepare all the work on my PC in Visual Studio and IIS express, all change is working well. So I do a local file system deploy and copy the content to the production server running IIS7.
Some fonts, glyphs are not display correctly. In the network tab I can see that all the file that does not load have a 301 permanent redirect and then 404 not found. I double-check the server directory the files are present.

The only thing I can see is the path is not the same. for example, on IIS Express:
http://localhost:49193/Content/kendo/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf?gedxeo
Then on the production site
http://ProductionSite.com/Content/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf?gedxeo

the source for the file is in the css like this: src:url(fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.eot?gedxeo)

Any idea?

UPDATE1
Mime definition:

```html
<dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress XML files -->
        <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress JavaScript files -->
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress JSON files -->
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress SVG files -->
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress RSS feeds -->
        <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress Atom feeds -->
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress ICO icon files (Note that most .ico files are uncompressed but there are some that can contain PNG compressed images. If you are doing this, remove this line). -->
        <add mimeType="image/x-icon" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress XML files -->
        <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress JavaScript files -->
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress JSON files -->
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress SVG files -->
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress EOT font files -->
        <add mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress TTF font files - application/font-ttf will probably be the new correct MIME type. IIS still uses application/x-font-ttf. -->
        <!--<add mimeType="application/font-ttf" enabled="true" />-->
        <add mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress OTF font files - application/font-opentype will probably be the new correct MIME type. IIS still uses font/otf. -->
        <!--<add mimeType="application/font-opentype" enabled="true" />-->
        <add mimeType="font/otf" enabled="true" />
        <!-- Compress RSS feeds -->
        <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
```

c

Comment: try to run the failed request tracing and check that what the actual issue [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis). is this path is under your site folder? Such issues could occur if the virtual directory for the StyleBundle for the Kendo UI styles has a root directory different than the physical one. This makes the relative path used for referencing the fonts incorrectly.

Comment: You should be able to resolve such issues if you define a separate StyleBundle for Kendo UI styles like this one (note that you may need to modify the path to match your folder structure exactly):`bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/2017.2.504/css").Include(
                "~/Content/kendo/2017.2.504/kendo.common.min.css",
                "~/Content/kendo/2017.2.504/kendo.default.min.css"));` . refernce [link](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/helper-basics/fundamentals?&_ga=2.258203530.1698796105.1570762428-1367997307.1570762428#css-bundling)

Comment: After many test. For now the only way to resolve my problem is to set: BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false; in the bunble config of my project.

Comment: I request you could post the solution as an answer and mark it. it will help other people who face a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why. My client use an very old IIS 7.5 server...
For now the only way to solve my problem is to add:
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false
into the bundle.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Mime Type. May mime type is not added for fonts on production server.